# How to import Liferay .lpkg theme into Liferay Developer Studio?

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I downloaded a Liferay theme from Liferay Marketplace, as a `.lpkg` file.
I want to modify it a bit.

How can I import it into Liferay Developer Studio?

I tried unzipping it, unzipping the `*-theme-*.war` inside, copying the folders to the root of a new Liferay theme project, compiling to WAR and copying to Liferay's `deploy` folder, but no theme appears. The theme appear correctly if I just copy the `.lpkg` file to `deploy`.

Comment: It should not happen. If you create a new theme and put all the files of downloaded theme to new theme's diff folder. Your theme should work just fine.

Comment: If you create a new theme.. Does that gets deployed and appears?